# CGI Module - Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, cgi

I found this [CGI Module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html), its letting me use HTML tags inside a python script.

ive seen some topics in here that shows how to use it, but when im using it it doesnt works.

```
import cgi
print ("""
<html>
<body>
Hello
</body>
</html>
""")
```

and this is the output when im running the script:

```
<html>
<body>
Hello
</body>
</html>
```

how can i use this properly?

thanks.

Comment: Your output looks fine to me. What did you expect to get?

Comment: @Kevin i was expecting to get      Hello, without the html tags

Answer (score 0):

If you have your CGI script already hooked up to a web server, you will need to emit the HTTP headers too, e.g.

```
print("Content-Type: text/html")     # HTML is following
print()                              # blank line, end of headers
print ("""
<html>
<body>
Hello
</body>
</html>
""")
```

Note that the `cgi` module is not being used in any way to achieve this; just simple calls to `print()`. The module is useful when you want to process form data submitted by a client through a HTML form.